# 404 Not Found error when deleting an entry

Tags: 404, delete, error-500

I've built several sites with EE but I've never had this error. In my last project, if I try to delete an entry (no matter from which channel) I receive a Not Found Page.

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /system/index.php was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I notice, however, that the entry is eventually deleted, but I can't give the client a site with this error and tell him to pretend nothing happened.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the $config['cp_url'] value in system/expressionengine/config/config.php is what you expect. It's usually something like 'http://www.yoursite.com/admin.php'.

Comment: Yes, it is admin.php. What else can I check?